# Правильно ли говорить "славить праздник"?

Tags: значение-слов, устаревшие-слова

Слышал как-то в одной песне фразу "славить праздник". В повседневной речи такого не встречал, хотя в других славянских языках слова, похожие на "славить", в подобном значении довольно часто употребляются. Правильно ли так говорить с точки зрения русского языка?

Comment: «Я слышу утренний колокол, он славит праздник»? Что ж тут некорректного?

Comment: @Ольга Я просто думал раньше, что славить можно только что-то одушевлённое. Поискал в интернете примеры, оказалось, что праздники особо никто и не славит (хотя в Чехии их обычно и славят, если говорить о похожих по звучанию словах).

Comment: Интересно, Roman, поняли Вы и как поняли ответ, который посчитали приемлемым?

Comment: @shampar Праздники славить тоже можно.

Comment: Что же сработало как доказательство?

Comment: @shampar Примеры употребления.

Comment: А точнее какие?

Comment: @shampar Стихотворение без авторства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**славить**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-79631.htm)
1. (сов. прославить).
*Восхвалять достоинства, доблесть, заслуги и т. д., создавая кому-либо, **чему-либо** славу, известность.*
Малый академический словарь русского языка

*— Я слышу, что тебя везде за песни славят

И с лучшими певцами рядом ставят.*
И. Крылов. Кошка и Соловей

***Отечество славлю***, которое есть, но трижды — которое будет.
В. Маяковский. Хорошо!

**Синонимы:** прославлять, славословить, хвалить, превозносить, восславлять, возвеличивать, расхваливать, увековечивать, воспевать, величать, покрывать славой.

По определению получается, что славить можно не только кого-то, но и ***что-то*** (отечество — неодушевлённое существительное), причём словарь не относит значение слова к устаревшим.
Мне попались такие стихи (без авторства):

*В апреле славный праздник

Россия отмечает:

День Космонавтики у нас.

**Прославил эту дату**

Обычный русский парень.

Мы **имя** его гордо **славим**,

Его зовут — Юрий Гагарин!*

*Всю жизнь я этот **праздник славлю** —

День мамы и её добра.*

Думаю, что словосочетание "славить праздник" вполне употребительно (встречается, правда, нечасто).

[Возможно, Вы слышали вот эту песенку:
*В праздник всех пищевиков каждый славить вас готов...*]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**
Комментарий: *Похоже, что славить надо людей, а не праздник.*

***Славься***, **Отечество** наше свободное,
Братских народов **союз** вековой,
Предками данная **мудрость** народная!
**Славься, страна**! Мы гордимся тобой!
С. Михалков. Гимн России

***Прославлен век*** двадцатый адресами
Великих строек плана ГОЭЛРО.
Р. Г. Айсин

[**Я *прославляю* каждый *дом*, где угощают молоком**](http://litcey.ru/biolog/38355/index.html)

*Я юности **славлю минуты**,

Часами меряя жизнь...*
Л. Киреев

*Я в жизнь **прославляю веру**...*
И. Елагин

Отечество, дата, страна, имя, мудрость, союз, век, минуты, вера, дом — это не люди.
Для кого-то день рождения сына или день первой встречи с любимой — праздник, который он славит (превозносит, возвеличивает, расхваливает, воспевает...).

**Дополнение к дополнению**

*Праздник светлый и свободный,

Славься, первый майский день!

...

Славься, праздник величавый!*
[**Неизвестный автор. Первое мая**](http://a-pesni.org/starrev/1maja-p.htm)

*Пускай успехов и добра прибавится,

Пускай любовь течет рекою быстрою.

А этот праздник на века пусть славится,

Соединяя судьбы с верой чистою!*

Comment: А какое «словосочетание вполне употребительно»? Которое здесь в примере про маму и её добро?

Comment: Похоже, что славить надо людей, а не праздник.

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ. Возможно, теперь моё мнение стало более понятным.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Песня совсем другая была, поищите в поисковике фразу "он славит праздник".

Comment: «Cловосочетание "славить праздник" вполне употребительно...», а ниже через строчку: «славить надо людей, а не праздник». За упокой получилось. Как же понимать такой ответ?

Comment: Эта фраза — комментарий @Romanа Podymovа, а не мои слова! После получения этого комментария я и даю своё дополнение к ответу, пытаясь это мнение опровергнуть.

Comment: Опровергаете утверждение «славить надо людей, а не праздник»?

Comment: "_Похоже,_ что славить надо людей, а не праздник" — это _не утверждение,_  а  м н е н и е спрашиваюшего. И я отвечаю: Отечество, дата, страна, имя, мудрость, союз, век, минуты, вера, дом — это не люди.
Для кого-то день рождения сына или день первой встречи с любимой — праздник, который он славит (превозносит, возвеличивает, расхваливает, воспевает...).

Comment: @shampar  "Славься, праздник величавый!" http://a-pesni.org/starrev/1maja-p.htm  "Пускай успехов и добра прибавится,
Пускай любовь течет рекою быстрою.
А этот праздник на века пусть славится,
Соединяя судьбы с верой чистою".

Comment: Вернитесь на землю, т. е. к вопросу: славить праздник!  Там не по отдельности: славить и — праздник, там форма глагола не возвратная, там  п р а з д н и к  — не подлежащее.

Answer (score 0):

На праздниках, т. е. торжественных собраниях, торжествах, прославляются виновники знаменательного (например, для церкви, государства и т. д.) события, а не сам праздник или дни праздника.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически можно славить кого угодно и что угодно. По смыслу, праздник *чего-то* (например, урожая) – это день славы этого самого чего-то (урожая) – Да здравствует урожай! А прославление самого праздника – это уже слава "второго порядка" (Да зравствует тот факт, что у нас есть праздник урожая!)